# Paypal : VISA MCC 9999 code issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

In my website, There is a payment option by using Paypal. Recently we received a few complaints from users who have not been able to do transactions because of the merchant category code being used on the account. we are using 9999 which does not exist in the VISA MCC code list. We are using child paypal Account for this. Please advise!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, but might be better to ask Paypal themselves? Also, are you sure your users are actually getting this error code (ie have you checked your logs etc)?

Comment: @JMK, Thanks for your response. Yes, They mailed me regarding this Issue. Note: Only few people are facing this error. I thought this is also official forum for Paypal.